# how to prevent the dataset from being closed in case of loss of connection to the server?

Tags: delphi, dataset

how to prevent the dataset from being closed in case of loss of connection to the server?

I have the following scenario:
I am editing the data in a form with dbedits and a dbgrid, then the network drops, when I click on the record button I have the treatment:

```
try
     FDQuery1.Post;
   except on E: Exception from
     begin
      ShowMessage ('Error writing letters' + sLineBreak + e.Message);
      Exit;
     end;
   end;
```

at that moment the network drops, and returns the message to the user above the exception, plus clicking OK in the message the dataset has already closed and dbgrid also no longer shows the data, it has to prevent this, and let the data stay in the screen?

Comment: Handle [exceptions properly](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Handling_Errors_(FireDAC)).

Comment: Use a TClientDataSet instead of connecting to the database directly. There is no way to keep a connection to the database if the connection drops.

Comment: the problem that I use unidac, can not change all the screens for clientdataset, a project with more than 50 forms and using unidac, wanted an alter...

Comment: Do Unidac datasets have `SaveToFile` and `LoadFromFile` methods that you could use to implement a "briefcase model" or save the data locally before you attempt to post if back to the server and restore it if the connection drops while posting changes back to the server?

Comment: I think it's not feasible to do this for all the screens, imagine the user loading 50 records in the query screen, saving and loading...

Comment: There is no way to survive losing the connection to the server without using TClientDataSet. If you want to do so, you're going to need to make the changes. Otherwise, get used to what you have  now.

Comment: @KenWhite is right.  "imagine the user loading 50 records"  Ok, I'm imagining, but why should the user even be aware that this is happening?  In any case, loading 50 records from a local file would be far faster than retrieving the same number again over a network from a server.

Comment: right. I always close every dataset when leaving the forms, and when I open it again, I open it and I noticed that it is slow like that, I did not want to have to open the whole database, all tables for the user to use.